# laravel populate select box

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I have seen similar questions asked before, but was unable to find a solution to my problem.  So I have a ClientController and within it this function

```
public function edit(Client $client)
{
    return view('clients.edit', compact('client'));
}
```

So that passes the client object to my edit view.  This view is pretty much the following

```
{!! Form::model($client, ['method' => 'PATCH', 'route' => ['clients.update', $client->slug]]) !!}
@include('clients/partials/_form', ['submit_text' => 'Edit Client'])
{!! Form::close() !!}
```

So it is using a partial for the form.  At the moment, the partial looks like so

```
<div class="form-group">
    {!! Form::label('clientName', 'Client Name:') !!}
    {!! Form::text('clientName') !!}
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    {!! Form::label('clientStatus', 'Client Status:') !!}
    {!! Form::select('clientStatus') !!}
</div>
```

When I visit the edit page for a client, I can see the form.  The clientName is populated with the clientName value.  The clientStatus is populated if I put it as a text input, but I cant get it to populate within a select as shown above.  Furthermore, clientStatus can either be New or Existing.  I need the select box to be pre-populated with the status of the client that is being edited, but I need the other option available within the select as well.  So if the clientStatus is New, New should be pre-selected within the select box and if I open the select, Existing should be the other option.

What would be the best way to achieve this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modify your select to include an array of the possible values.

Basic Select - Label is value

```
{!! Form::select('clientStatus',['New','Existing']) !!}
```

Key Value Select - Key is value

```
{!! Form::select('clientStatus',[ 1 => 'New', 2 => 'Existing']) !!}
```

Form model will then set the value in the select to the one in the model.

More information see the [docs](http://laravelcollective.com/docs/5.1/html#drop-down-lists).

Comment: I was to write the solution but you come with it first, vote up.